# i want 10，why always just 9 in mysql？

Tags: mysql, sql

I can get 10 items here and when the m < 21404 : 
[image: Select query returning 10 items when m < 21404]

I can just get 9 items here and when the m > 21405
[image: Select query returning 10 items when m > 21405]

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sessionid)
FROM js_plugin_searchlog
WHERE 1=1 AND searchdate >= '20170607' AND searchdate <= '20170817';
```

result is 169859 here,and if I change the "20170607" in pic2,the result of pic2 will be normal,can get 10 items always, so what is the problem ?

Comment: I would first try to add `order by sessionid` before `limit`.

Comment: Whenever possible put dates in a `DATE` field in [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (`YYYY-MM-DD`) so they can be sorted, indexed, and compared in a meaningful way. You can do any conversion for display by the user later, and at that point take into account things like the user's personal preferences.

Comment: maybe i  will never face this problem any more，i just change the searchdate interval and then this problem will disapper。just don't begin with ‘20170607’ it will be ok，add “order by” is not my need ,wasting more time.i just wonder where it come from

Comment: You can't retrieve more rows than are actually possible.  Remove the `LIMIT` and you should find that only ~21414 rows are found, total.